# Recursive SQL CTE in Azure Synapse

Tags: sql, recursion, pyspark, common-table-expression, azure-synapse

I'm trying to rewrite some Oracle code in Azure Synapse Pyspark notebook, however some of the code is written as a recursive CTE. I have no idea how to convert it. I've been at it several days and no luck. Does anyone have any idea on a good way to rewrite this piece of code? The "recursiveCTE" is being called inside of the CTE itself which isn't allowed in Synpase.

The secret is in the recursiveCTE.columnTwo

Table one, column two = ola.columnTwo where  in (1006, 1011)

Table two, column two = ol2.columnTwo where in (1007)

Table two, appended into columnFour recursively = recursiveCTE.columnTwo (should contain columnTwo where in 1006, 1007, 1011)

```
WHERE nvl(ol2.reference_line_id,nvl(ol2.source_document_line_id,to_number(ol2.return_attribute2) ) ) = recursiveCTE.columnTwo


SELECT * FROM recursiveCTE where columnONE = 1678544 and columnSeven = 547793
```

should output 3 rows of data (not 2 rows):

```
ColumnOne|ColumnTwo|ColumnThree|ColumnFour|ColumnFive|ColumnSix|ColumnSeven 

1678544 16227012    1006    (null)      1   16227012    547793  160

1678544 14123334    1007    16227012    2   16227012    547793  -62

1678544 14123337    1007    14123334    3   16227012    547793  -21
```

```
recursiveCTE AS (
    SELECT
        ola.columnOne,
        ola.columnTwo,
        ola.columnThree,
        nvl(ola.reference_line_id,nvl(ola.source_document_line_id,to_number(ola.return_attribute2) ) ) AS     columnFour,
        1 AS columnFive,
        ola.line_id AS columnSix,
        ola.columnSeven, 
        ola.columnEight
    FROM
        tableOne ola
    WHERE
        ola.columnOne IN (select header_ids.columnOne from header_ids)
        AND ola.cancelled_flag = 'N'
        AND ola.columnThree IN (
            1006,
            1011
        )
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        ol2.columnOne,
        ol2.columnTwo,
        ol2.columnThree,
        recursiveCTE.columnTwo,
        lvl + 1 AS columnFive,
        recursiveCTE.ref_orig_line_id AS columnSix,
        ol2.columnSeven, 
        ol2.fulfilled_quantity * -1 as columnEight
    FROM
        tableOne ol2,
        recursiveCTE
    WHERE
        nvl(ol2.reference_line_id,nvl(ol2.source_document_line_id,to_number(ol2.return_attribute2) ) ) = recursiveCTE.columnTwo
        AND ol2.columnOne IN (select header_ids.columnOne from header_ids)
        AND ol2.cancelled_flag = 'N'
        AND ol2.columnThree IN (
            1007
        )
),
```

Answer (score 1):

Azure Synapse Analytics does not support recursive CTEs like in SQL Server or Oracle. Therefore, the best approach is to refactor the recursive CTE using iterative methods in a PySpark notebook.

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

# Initial DataFrame corresponding to the base case of your recursive CTE
base_df = spark.sql("""
    SELECT
        ola.columnOne,
        ola.columnTwo,
        ola.columnThree,
        nvl(ola.reference_line_id, nvl(ola.source_document_line_id, to_number(ola.return_attribute2))) AS columnFour,
        1 AS columnFive,
        ola.line_id AS columnSix,
        ola.columnSeven, 
        ola.columnEight
    FROM
        tableOne ola
    WHERE
        ola.columnOne IN (select header_ids.columnOne from header_ids)
        AND ola.cancelled_flag = 'N'
        AND ola.columnThree IN (1006, 1011)
""")

# You can use the iterative approach to replicate the recursive CTE logic
previous_count = 0
limit = 1000  # Just as a safety precaution to avoid infinite loops
iteration = 0

while True and iteration < limit:
    # Join base_df with tableOne on the recursive condition
    recursive_join = base_df.alias("recursiveCTE").join(
        spark.table("tableOne").alias("ol2"),
        F.expr("nvl(ol2.reference_line_id, nvl(ol2.source_document_line_id, to_number(ol2.return_attribute2))) = recursiveCTE.columnTwo")
        & (F.col("ol2.columnOne").isin(spark.sql("select header_ids.columnOne from header_ids")))
        & (F.col("ol2.cancelled_flag") == 'N')
        & (F.col("ol2.columnThree") == 1007),
        "inner"
    ).select(
        F.col("ol2.columnOne"),
        F.col("ol2.columnTwo"),
        F.col("ol2.columnThree"),
        F.col("recursiveCTE.columnTwo"),
        (F.col("recursiveCTE.columnFive") + 1).alias("columnFive"),
        F.col("recursiveCTE.columnSix"),
        F.col("ol2.columnSeven"),
        (F.col("ol2.columnEight") * -1).alias("columnEight")
    )
    
    new_count = recursive_join.count()
    
    # Check if we have any new rows
    if new_count == previous_count:
        break
    else:
        base_df = base_df.union(recursive_join)
        previous_count = new_count
        iteration += 1

# base_df now contains the full result
base_df.show()
```

### EDIT:

One way to eliminate the recursive CTE is to use a series of JOIN operations to simulate the recursion. But there is a catch - without knowing the maximum depth of the recursion, we cannot determine how many JOINs we need.

```sql
-- First layer (base case)
WITH layer1 AS (
    SELECT
        ola.columnOne,
        ola.columnTwo,
        ola.columnThree,
        nvl(ola.reference_line_id, nvl(ola.source_document_line_id, to_number(ola.return_attribute2))) AS columnFour,
        1 AS columnFive,
        ola.line_id AS columnSix,
        ola.columnSeven,
        ola.columnEight
    FROM
        tableOne ola
    WHERE
        ola.columnOne IN (select header_ids.columnOne from header_ids)
        AND ola.cancelled_flag = 'N'
        AND ola.columnThree IN (1006, 1011)
),

-- Second layer
layer2 AS (
    SELECT
        ol2.columnOne,
        ol2.columnTwo,
        ol2.columnThree,
        l1.columnTwo AS columnFour,
        2 AS columnFive,
        l1.columnSix AS columnSix,
        ol2.columnSeven,
        ol2.fulfilled_quantity * -1 as columnEight
    FROM
        tableOne ol2
    JOIN layer1 l1
        ON nvl(ol2.reference_line_id, nvl(ol2.source_document_line_id, to_number(ol2.return_attribute2))) = l1.columnTwo
    WHERE
        ol2.columnOne IN (select header_ids.columnOne from header_ids)
        AND ol2.cancelled_flag = 'N'
        AND ol2.columnThree IN (1007)
),

-- Third layer
layer3 AS (
    SELECT
        ol2.columnOne,
        ol2.columnTwo,
        ol2.columnThree,
        l2.columnTwo AS columnFour,
        3 AS columnFive,
        l2.columnSix AS columnSix,
        ol2.columnSeven,
        ol2.fulfilled_quantity * -1 as columnEight
    FROM
        tableOne ol2
    JOIN layer2 l2
        ON nvl(ol2.reference_line_id, nvl(ol2.source_document_line_id, to_number(ol2.return_attribute2))) = l2.columnTwo
    WHERE
        ol2.columnOne IN (select header_ids.columnOne from header_ids)
        AND ol2.cancelled_flag = 'N'
        AND ol2.columnThree IN (1007)
)

-- Final result
SELECT * FROM layer1 
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM layer2 
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM layer3 
WHERE columnONE = 1678544 AND columnSeven = 547793;
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this. I'm currently trying to convert it to SQL code. I misspoke when I said I wanted it in PySpark. I'm running it in a PySpark notebook but it's only running as SQL code. Is there anyway you can rewrite it as SQL code for me? If not, I'll try to convert it myself.

Comment: @mohamadmaarouf_ I am a little bit confused what you shared is already in SQL

Comment: This solution doesn't work. There's supposed to be 3 rows of data as the answer, not two. The CTE is being called upon itself in the from clause of the second select statement. Thanks for attempt though, i appreciate it. I still came up with 2 rows of data instead of three. "ColumnTwo" is being called recursively, its a "line_id". Line_id where line_type_id in (1006, 1011) appended on top of line_id where line_type_id in (1007) in the two where clauses.

Comment: You didn't share your input and expected output. Help us to help you :)

Comment: please update your question with the details and not in comments

Comment: Hi Amira, I updated my question. Please take a look when you get the chance.

Comment: Hi Amira, thank you for all your help. I was able to answer my own question. Please see the answer below. It's the same exact answer as yours except I did a loop in PySpark in order to allow for higher recursion depth. I will keep your answer on hand, however, as someone may need to replicate the recursive CTE with just SQL and not PySpark. Thanks.

Comment: When I saw the answer, I can clearly understand that you failed in explaining your issue. Next time try to provide a more structured question.

Answer (score 0):

Created Sample dataframe according to your sparksql query to understand your code
note:-(changed to_number to cast as spar.sql not accepting to_number)

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("SparkSQLRecursiveDataFrame").getOrCreate()
,)]
header_ids_columns = ["columnOne"]
ola_data = [
    (1, 1, "Value2", 1006, 201, "Attribute2", 301, "Value7", "N", 1, 401, 44, None, 22),
    (2, 6, "Value3", 102, 202, "Attribute2", 302, "Value7", "N", 1, 402, 66, 201, 20),
    (3, 2, "Value4", 1011, 203, "Attribute2", 303, "Value7", "N", 1, 403, 77, 202, 30)
]
ola_columns = [
    "line_id",
    "columnOne",
    "columnTwo",
    "columnThree",
    "source_document_line_id",
    "return_attribute2",
    "orig_line_id_1",
    "columnSeven",
    "cancelled_flag",
    "columnFive",
    "columnSix",
    "columnEight",
    "reference_line_id",
    "fulfilled_quantity"
]
header_ids_df = spark.createDataFrame(header_ids_data, header_ids_columns)
ola_df = spark.createDataFrame(ola_data, ola_columns)
header_ids_df.show()
ola_df.show()
header_ids_df.createOrReplaceTempView("header_ids")
ola_df.createOrReplaceTempView("tableOne")
recursive_query = """
   
       WITH  recursiveCTE AS (
        SELECT
            ola.columnOne,
            ola.columnTwo,
            ola.columnThree,
            IFNULL(ola.reference_line_id, IFNULL(ola.source_document_line_id, CAST(ola.return_attribute2 AS INT))) AS columnFour,
            1 AS columnFive,
            ola.orig_line_id_1 AS columnSix,
            ola.columnSeven,
            ola.columnEight
        FROM
            tableOne ola
        WHERE
            ola.columnOne IN (SELECT header_ids.columnOne FROM header_ids)
            AND ola.cancelled_flag = 'N'
            AND ola.columnThree IN (1006, 1011))
        SELECT * From recursiveCTE
        UNION ALL
        SELECT
            ol2.columnOne,
            ol2.columnTwo,
            ol2.columnThree,
            recursiveCTE.columnFour,
            recursiveCTE.columnFive + 1 AS columnFive,
            ol2.orig_line_id_1 AS columnSix,
            ol2.columnSeven,
            -1 * ol2.fulfilled_quantity AS columnEight
        FROM
            tableOne ol2,
            recursiveCTE
        WHERE
            nvl(ol2.reference_line_id,nvl(ol2.source_document_line_id,CAST(ol2.return_attribute2 AS INT) ) ) = recursiveCTE.columnTwo
            AND ol2.columnOne IN (select header_ids.columnOne from header_ids)
            AND ol2.cancelled_flag = 'N'
            AND ol2.columnThree IN (1007)
"""
result_df = spark.sql(recursive_query)
result_df.show()
```

OUTPUT:

```
+---------+
|columnOne|
+---------+
|        1|
|        2|
|        3|
+---------+

+-------+---------+---------+-----------+-----------------------+-----------------+--------------+-----------+--------------+----------+---------+-----------+-----------------+------------------+
|line_id|columnOne|columnTwo|columnThree|source_document_line_id|return_attribute2|orig_line_id_1|columnSeven|cancelled_flag|columnFive|columnSix|columnEight|reference_line_id|fulfilled_quantity|
+-------+---------+---------+-----------+-----------------------+-----------------+--------------+-----------+--------------+----------+---------+-----------+-----------------+------------------+
|      1|        1|   Value2|       1006|                    201|       Attribute2|           301|     Value7|             N|         1|      401|         44|             null|                22|
|      2|        6|   Value3|        102|                    202|       Attribute2|           302|     Value7|             N|         1|      402|         66|              201|                20|
|      3|        2|   Value4|       1011|                    203|       Attribute2|           303|     Value7|             N|         1|      403|         77|              202|                30|
+-------+---------+---------+-----------+-----------------------+-----------------+--------------+-----------+--------------+----------+---------+-----------+-----------------+------------------+

+---------+---------+-----------+----------+----------+---------+-----------+-----------+
|columnOne|columnTwo|columnThree|columnFour|columnFive|columnSix|columnSeven|columnEight|
+---------+---------+-----------+----------+----------+---------+-----------+-----------+
|        1|   Value2|       1006|       201|         1|      301|     Value7|         44|
|        2|   Value4|       1011|       202|         1|      303|     Value7|         77|
+---------+---------+-----------+----------+----------+---------+-----------+-----------+
```

Now changing the spark spark sql statement to data frame transformation
to match the spark sql output

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, when, lit, expr

spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("RecursiveDataFrame").getOrCreate()

header_ids_data = [(1,), (2,), (3,)]
header_ids_columns = ["columnOne"]

ola_data = [
    (1, 1, "Value2", 1006, 201, "Attribute2", 301, "Value7", "N", 1, 401, 44, None, 22),
    (2, 6, "Value3", 102, 202, "Attribute2", 302, "Value7", "N", 1, 402, 66, 201, 20),
    (3, 2, "Value4", 1011, 203, "Attribute2", 303, "Value7", "N", 1, 403, 77, 202, 30)
]
ola_columns = [
    "line_id",
    "columnOne",
    "columnTwo",
    "columnThree",
    "source_document_line_id",
    "return_attribute2",
    "orig_line_id_1",
    "columnSeven",
    "cancelled_flag",
    "columnFive",
    "columnSix",
    "columnEight",
    "reference_line_id",
    "fulfilled_quantity"
]

header_ids_df = spark.createDataFrame(header_ids_data, header_ids_columns)
ola_df = spark.createDataFrame(ola_data, ola_columns)

initial_df = ola_df.alias("ol1") \
    .join(header_ids_df.alias("header_ids"), ["columnOne"], "inner") \
    .filter((col("ol1.cancelled_flag") == "N") & (col("ol1.columnThree").isin([1006, 1011]))) \
    .select(
        col("ol1.columnOne"),
        col("ol1.columnTwo"),
        col("ol1.columnThree"),
        when(col("ol1.reference_line_id").isNull(),
             when(col("ol1.source_document_line_id").isNull(),
                  col("ol1.return_attribute2"))
             .otherwise(col("ol1.source_document_line_id")))
        .otherwise(col("ol1.reference_line_id")).alias("columnFour"),
        lit(1).alias("columnFive"),
        col("ol1.orig_line_id_1").alias("columnSix"),
        col("ol1.columnSeven"),
        col("ol1.columnEight")
    )

recursive_expr = expr("""
    IFNULL(ol2.reference_line_id, 
           IFNULL(ol2.source_document_line_id, CAST(ol2.return_attribute2 AS INT)))
""")

result_df = initial_df.union(
    ola_df.alias("ol2")
    .join(initial_df.alias("initial"), recursive_expr == col("initial.columnFour"), "inner")
    .filter((col("ol2.cancelled_flag") == "N") & (col("ol2.columnThree") == 1007))
    .select(
        col("ol2.columnOne"),
        col("ol2.columnTwo"),
        col("ol2.columnThree"),
        col("initial.columnFour"),
        (col("initial.columnFive") + 1).alias("columnFive"),
        col("ol2.orig_line_id_1").alias("columnSix"),
        col("ol2.columnSeven"),
        (-1 * col("ol2.fulfilled_quantity")).alias("columnEight")
    )
)
header_ids_df.show()
ola_df.show()
result_df.show()
```

OUTPUT:

```
+---------+
|columnOne|
+---------+
|        1|
|        2|
|        3|
+---------+

+-------+---------+---------+-----------+-----------------------+-----------------+--------------+-----------+--------------+----------+---------+-----------+-----------------+------------------+
|line_id|columnOne|columnTwo|columnThree|source_document_line_id|return_attribute2|orig_line_id_1|columnSeven|cancelled_flag|columnFive|columnSix|columnEight|reference_line_id|fulfilled_quantity|
+-------+---------+---------+-----------+-----------------------+-----------------+--------------+-----------+--------------+----------+---------+-----------+-----------------+------------------+
|      1|        1|   Value2|       1006|                    201|       Attribute2|           301|     Value7|             N|         1|      401|         44|             null|                22|
|      2|        6|   Value3|        102|                    202|       Attribute2|           302|     Value7|             N|         1|      402|         66|              201|                20|
|      3|        2|   Value4|       1011|                    203|       Attribute2|           303|     Value7|             N|         1|      403|         77|              202|                30|
+-------+---------+---------+-----------+-----------------------+-----------------+--------------+-----------+--------------+----------+---------+-----------+-----------------+------------------+

+---------+---------+-----------+----------+----------+---------+-----------+-----------+
|columnOne|columnTwo|columnThree|columnFour|columnFive|columnSix|columnSeven|columnEight|
+---------+---------+-----------+----------+----------+---------+-----------+-----------+
|        1|   Value2|       1006|       201|         1|      301|     Value7|         44|
|        2|   Value4|       1011|       202|         1|      303|     Value7|         77|
+---------+---------+-----------+----------+----------+---------+-----------+-----------+
```

I think this is your requirement

Comment: This solution doesn't work because it's supposed to be recursive. There's supposed to be 3 rows of data as the answer, not two. The CTE is being called upon itself in the from clause of the second select statement. Thanks for attempt though, i appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to answer my own question using ChatGPT, which gave me the wrong answer a thousand times, but I was able to combine several different answers into one and solve for a final answer. You can set the max_recursion_depth to a high number like "50" and append all the answers together or keep it at a low number if you don't need a high recursion depth.

```
recursion_result = spark.sql("""
    SELECT
        ola.columnOne,
        ola.columnTwo,
        ola.columnThree,
       CASE
           WHEN ola.reference_line_id IS NOT NULL THEN 
       ola.reference_line_id
           WHEN ola.source_document_line_id IS NOT NULL THEN 
       ola.source_document_line_id
           ELSE CAST(ola.return_attribute2 AS INT)
       END AS columnFour,
       1 AS columnFive,
       ola.columnTwo AS columnSix,
       ola.columnSeven, 
       ola.columnEight
       FROM
           tableOne ola
       WHERE
           ola.columnOne IN (SELECT columnOne FROM header_ids)
           AND ola.cancelled_flag = 'N'
           AND ola.columnThree IN (1006, 1011)
    """)


recursion_results = []
recursion_results.append(recursion_result)

i = 0
max_recursion_depth = 5  # You can adjust this value
for i in range(max_recursion_depth):
    recursion_result.createOrReplaceTempView("recursion_result")
    
    recursion_result = spark.sql("""
        SELECT
            ol2.columnOne,
            ol2.columnTwo,
            ol2.columnThree,
            rr.columnTwo AS columnFour,
            rr.columnFive + 1 AS columnFive,
            rr.columnSix,
            ol2.columnSeven,
            -1 * ol2.columnEight AS columnEight
        FROM
            tableTwo ol2
        JOIN
            recursion_result rr
        ON
            (CASE
                WHEN ol2.reference_line_id IS NOT NULL THEN ol2.reference_line_id
                WHEN ol2.source_document_line_id IS NOT NULL THEN ol2.source_document_line_id
                ELSE CAST(ol2.return_attribute2 AS INT)
            END) = rr.columnTwo
        WHERE
            ol2.cancelled_flag = 'N'
            AND ol2.columnThree = 1007
    """)
    recursion_results.append(recursion_result)



combined_df = recursion_results[0]  # Initialize with the first DataFrame
for df in recursion_results[1:]:
    combined_df = combined_df.union(df)

# Show the final result
combined_df.createOrReplaceTempView("final_results")
```