# Calculate the compound running total of a calculation

Tags: sql-server, azure-synapse

I am trying to achieve the following results

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ELn79.png)

Formula for Compound running total is (value + 1) * (previous_value + 1) - 1

I am trying to execute the following query in synapse

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT date, value, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY date) AS seqnum
    FROM table_name
), cte2 AS (
    SELECT cte.date, cte.value, cte.seqnum
    FROM cte
    WHERE seqnum = 1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT cte.date, (cte.value + 1) * (cte2.value + 1) - 1, cte.seqnum
    FROM cte2
    JOIN cte ON cte.seqnum = cte2.seqnum + 1
)
SELECT cte2.date, cte2.value
FROM cte2;
```

I am getting the following error:

> Recursive common table expressions are not supported in this version.

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76984911/recursive-sql-cte-in-azure-synapse#:~:text=Azure%20Synapse%20Analytics%20does%20not,methods%20in%20a%20PySpark%20notebook.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know, I am new to posting a question in stackoverflow

Comment: There is a tour and a guide to asking which explains it all :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may not need recursion. A compound interest calculation is essentially a running product calculation. It would be nice if DBMSs would implement aggregate `prod()` function similar to `sum()`, but most (all?) do not. The good news is that you can change your product operation into a sum operation using logarithms.

*(Anyone who remembers mechanical slide rules or is familiar with the inner workings of WWII-era battleship targeting computers knows that.)*

The equivalent of a hypothetical `prod(value)` function is `exp(sum(log(value)))`. When dealing with relative percentages or fractions (offset by 100% or 1.0), the equivalent is `exp(sum(log(value + 1))) - 1`.

Your query might then become something relatively simple like:

```
SELECT
    D.*,
    EXP(SUM(LOG(D.Interest + 1)) OVER(ORDER BY D.Id)) - 1 AS CummulativeInterest
FROM Data D
ORDER BY D.Id
```

I am not sure if this will work as written in Synapse, but your original posted query seemed to support windowed aggregates.

Results:

| Id | Interest | Cummulative Interest (Rounded) | Cummulative Interest (Raw) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 2 | 0.0606 | 0.0606 | 0.0606 |
| 3 | 0.0031 | 0.0639 | 0.0638878600000001 |
| 4 | 0.0002 | 0.0641 | 0.0641006375720001 |
| 5 | 0.0006 | 0.0647 | 0.0647390979545432 |
| 6 | 0 | 0.0647 | 0.0647390979545432 |
| 7 | 0 | 0.0647 | 0.0647390979545432 |
| 8 | 0.0439 | 0.1115 | 0.111481144354748 |
| 9 | 0 | 0.1115 | 0.111481144354748 |
| 10 | 0 | 0.1115 | 0.111481144354748 |
| 11 | 0.0001 | 0.1116 | 0.111592292469183 |
| 12 | 0 | 0.1116 | 0.111592292469183 |

See [this db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/yBAWouUp) for a demo.